# Relativity theory inconsistency

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, time, observers

Suppose I have two synced clocks, light-based for simplicity (light bouncing between mirrors up and down).

A train comes by me at some velocity u and I put one of the clocks on the moving train.

According to theory of relativity, my perceived period of the clock that is now on a train is $1/\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$ times bigger than the clock that I kept to myself.

But at the same time that should be true if we consider the situation from the perspective of the train, relative to which I am moving at the same absolute speed. So, their perceived period of my clock should be same amount of times larger.

So how can our clocks be faster than each other in the same > 1 amount of times?

Comment: That is not an inconsistency. That is a directly experimentally verified prediction of SR. It is just not possible to have a clock system without this problem. Understanding this is critical to the understanding of what the theory is trying to tell us about the nature of our universe.

Comment: "Inconsistencies" and "paradoxes" (yes, I'm also talking about the twins paradox) are commonly referred to as such because our everyday perception of classical physics gets confused, but they are NEITHER of those things.

Comment: This is basically exactly the very often discussed "the twin paradox." I'd recommend reading about it or watching youtube videos about it.  In the end it is not a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

You are confused because you misunderstand time dilation. What it means is that if you compare the reading of the clock on the train with the readings of two stationary clocks that it passes, then the time interval shown by the moving clock is less than the time interval between the readings on the stationary clocks. *That is not because the moving clock is ticking more slowly than either of the stationary clocks.*  It is because the two stationary clocks are out of synch with time in the frame of the moving clock. The effect is entirely symmetrical. If there are two clocks on the train, and you compare the stationary clock in you hand with each of the clocks on the train as they go past you, you will find that the time elapsed on your stationary clock is less than the difference in the readings between the two moving clocks- ie it is your stationary clock which seems time dilated. Again that is not because your clock is ticking more slowly than either of the individual moving clocks, but because the two moving clocks are out of synch compared with time in your frame.

The so called paradox you describe assumes that a single moving clock ticks more slowly than a single stationary one, which is simply a mistake.

Comment: Can you explain where my derivation is wrong? I simply want to consider the situation described: I put a clock on the train, then take it off after some time and compare with the stationary one. As I understand, theory of relativity predicts that the train-traveled one will show less time elapsed, since it was going slower in my frame of reference (because I see light doing zigzags). But at the same time it should be the other way around, if an observer on a train does the same deduction, since it was my clock that was moving for him. I just wanna compare exact amount of ticks that clocks did.

Comment: You haven't thought about my answer properly!  If you put a clock on a passing train, how can you ever compare it with the clock in your hand? It is gone off at speed. How do you propose to make the comparison?

Comment: By getting it on another train that will get it back, let's say. From what I read on wiki people say that acceleration experienced by the clock does not matter.

Comment: I understand that when we are moving, imaginary stationary synchronized clocks are all appearing not only slowly running, but also unsynched, which can make up for the slowing part and make all stationary clocks encountered outrun us. But how can the one exact physical clock that always appears slow become unsynched with itself, and outrun us? Also, isn't it possible to tell who was _really moving_ if the one who was moving will have their clock show less time elapsed?

Comment: If you put it on another train to bring it back, that is an example of the 'twin paradox'.   The clock that has reversed direction will record a shorter time interval. Don't forget that acceleration is absolute, so you can know which clock changed direction.

Comment: It is all about the geometry of spacetime. The interval between two events might be 5s in one frame and 4s in another, say. Clocks will measure the interval. If a clock in one frame measures 4s and clocks in another measure 5s, it is not because the first clock is running slow but that the interval is actually shorter. It is just like the odometer in a car. If you drive round a circle while I drive across it, my odometer will record less than yours- it is not 'distance dilated'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145976/discussion-between-user87035-and-marco-ocram).

Answer (score 0):

Einstein's 1905 postulates, true or false, entail the following conclusion:

If two clocks are initially stationary and synchronized but then one moves towards and finally meets the other, either clock will see the other lagging behind.

The conclusion is validly deducible from the postulates but is obviously absurd, which shows that at least one of the postulates is false (reductio ad absurdum). So if Einstein had obeyed logic in 1905, Max Planck would not have found courage to publish his paper.

Einstein fraudulently tweaked the conclusion and camouflaged the absurdity. Here is the tweaked version:

If two clocks are initially stationary and synchronized but then one moves towards and finally meets the other, the stationary clock will see the moving clock lagging behind while the moving clock will see the stationary running fast.

And the fraudulent text:

Albert Einstein, On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies, 1905: "From this there ensues the following peculiar consequence. If at the points A and B of K there are stationary clocks which, viewed in the stationary system, are synchronous; and if the clock at A is moved with the velocity v along the line AB to B, then on its arrival at B the two clocks no longer synchronize, but the clock moved from A to B lags behind the other which has remained at B by tv^2/2c^2 (up to magnitudes of fourth and higher order), t being the time occupied in the journey from A to B." http://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/www/

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Suppose two clocks are initially synchronised and some distance apart. At 12:00 they then each accelerate at the same time and at the same rate toward each other. When they meet, they will show the same time, say 12:10. However, each will consider the other to be time dilated because each will consider that in their frame the other clock started its journey earlier than 12:00.